# How do I use jQuery to select this div and change the html?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="scroller-pane">
    <div class="scroller-header"></div>
    <div class="scroller-division" id="0">
        <div style="height:20px;"></div>
        <div class="title">A day with bears</div>
        <div class="date">30/06/2011</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...</div>
        <div style="float:right;"><a href="htp://www.google.com">more>></a></div>
    </div>
<div>
```

And I have called:

```
console.log($('.scroller-pane .scroller-division #0 .title').html());
```

and

```
console.log($('.scroller-pane > .scroller-division > #0 > .title').html());
```

But all I get is 'undefined', why have neither of these select statement not worked? How do I write a jQuery select statement to get to the 'title' div..?

Comment: i dont think you can have an `id` starting with a number.

Comment: read the section here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp

Comment: For more info on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @Daniel: w3schools is out of date. "0" is a valid `id` in HTML5. It's invalid in HTML4.01 and earlier, and invalid in CSS, and I would never use it, but it's valid in HTML5 (see my answer for links to references).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ID of the element, just target it by that:

```
console.log($('#0').children('div.title').html());
```

Comment: `id` in `javascript` can not start with numbers

Answer (score 0):

> And I have called:
>
> `console.log($('.scroller-pane .scroller-division #0 .title').html());`

That says "Find all elements with class "title" that are descendants of an element with the `id` "0" that's a descendant of an element with the class "scroller-division" which is a descendant of an element with class "scroller-pane". But your element with id "0" *is* the "scroller-division", it's not a descendant of it.

If you really want to target this *only* if the element with `id` "0" is nested in that way, and to do nothing otherwise, you'd do this:

```
console.log($('.scroller-pane .scroller-division .title').html());
```

or

```
console.log($('.scroller-pane #0 .title').html());
```

or

```
console.log($('.scroller-pane .scroller-division[id=0] .title').html());
```

(That last will ignore elements with `id` "0" if they don't have the class "scroller-division".)

But if you want to target the "title" descendants of `id` "0" regardless of where it is, it gets a lot shorter:

```
console.log($('#0 .title').html());
```

---

**Off-topic**: ***Strongly*** recommend you don't use "0" as an `id` value. It's [valid in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), but it's [invalid in HTML4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and earlier (`id`s can't start with a digit), and it's [invalid in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (same).

Comment: `id` in `javascript` can not start with numbers

Comment: @Miroprocessor: JavaScript has nothing to say about `id` values one way or the other. HTML and CSS do. Curiously, I was just adding a recommendation to the author not to use "0" as an ID, but it ***is*** valid as of HTML5 (it's not valid in HTML4.01 or CSS).

Comment: I think given the general tone of me using numbers for ID's its not a good ides...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I don't know it is valid in Html5, but I the author didn't mention if he uses Html5 or not any way, thanks for that new info

Comment: @Pete2k: Yeah, as I said above, I ***strongly*** recommended not using it. Just put an "x" in front of it or something (e.g., `x0`), then it's valid in all three standards. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can just access it via the id, using `$('#id')` however I think that it's not allowed to have a number as the first character of an id

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to change the html or retrieve it, but here's examples of both:

http://jsfiddle.net/wUV5r/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('.scroller-pane .scroller-division[id=0] .title').html());
    $('.scroller-pane .scroller-division[id=0] .title').html('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($('.scroller-pane .scroller-division#0 .title').html());
```